# Scraping length of video on LinkedIn

Tags: web-scraping, apify

I am trying to scrape the duration of video published to LinkedIn, using the Apify webscraper.

**The problem (in brief)**

I have found the length of the video stored as text in the LinkedIn HTML. When I attempt to use the webscraper to return this text, it gives me nothing. I don't know what I've done wrong.

**LinkedIn HTML**

From inspecting the page HTML, I have found the duration of video contained in the following element:

```
<span class="vjs-duration-display" aria-live="off" role="presentation">1:00</span>
```

(In this example, the duration of the video is one minute).

This line of code is unique; 'vjs-duration-display' does not appear anywhere else in the HTML.

**Apify Webscraper**

Treating this information as text, I have attempted to scrape this information using the 'return' function.

The full page function can be seen below, with the 'return' function found in lines five to eight:

```
async function pageFunction(context) {
    const { request, log, jQuery: $ } = context;
    if (request.userData.label === "PAGE"){
    log.info('LinkedIn page opened');}
    return {
        url: context.request.url,
        duration: $('span[class=vjs-duration-display]').text,
    };
}
```

The programme loads the LinkedIn page and returns the URL, but not the video duration.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: hey there, I would advise to learn the basics of CSS selectors and jQuery first instead of jumping directly to scraping

Comment: Ok, thank you. There is a course on DataCamp on CSS selectors which I've started, so I will power through with that.